# MongoDB PHP how to count elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection/table document/record which contains a number of fields including an array for telephone. Some documents/records in the collection/table will have 1 telephone while others may have many. How can I test the array to see how many elements/telephones are in it using PHP? Thank you for your help.

Comment: [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please post your JSON data it will much helpful to understand, According to your explanation -

```
db.collection.aggregate({$project:{AnyVarName:{$size:"$telephone"}}});
```

Feel free to convert this in PHP Implementation